# Clean files queued for deletion through File.deleteOnExit

Tags: java, file, java-io

I have some [library code](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/a98eaeb917943adcd6bfe04c9e446d59a94f7de2/src/java/org/apache/poi/util/DefaultTempFileCreationStrategy.java#L113-L115) that uses [`File.deleteOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()). As this piece of code is called a lot in my application, memory keeps piling up in [`DeleteOnExitHook`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/DeleteOnExitHook.java#L37). This causes my heap to grow indefinitely and eventually causes `OutOfMemoryErrors`. As the class is completely package protected, there seems trivial mechanism to intermediately delete the files enqueued for deletion. Can I get this empty this list with some reflection magic?

Comment: After reading a bit, `deleteOnExit()` seems to be a very strange and partially dangerous method. It will store only Strings of files to delete on "normal termination", which is most likly `System.exit(0)`. With any other termination, like a hard power-off or `kill` or even `System.exit(1)`, the files won't be deleted. So I would try to avoid using `deleteOnExit()` by all means. Can you replace the used library with another one, not using that method? You actually could use reflections to change the visibility and overwrite the method with a plain `delete`.

Comment: Alternativly, most likly not very convenient, fork the library, rewrite that code, build it yourself. (And maybe create a pull request?)

Comment: I am willing to submit a patch there but its probably going to take ages for it to get merged, a workaround hack would be nice hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need a dirty hack, so this should suffice.  You need to restore `files` field value so that normal shutdown (or next time you use this hack) works fine.

Note: will delete everything, including files scheduled by other libraries. Make sure to check it is safe in your case.

```
    java.lang.reflect.Method  run   = Class.forName ("java.io.DeleteOnExitHook").getDeclaredMethod ("runHooks");
    java.lang.reflect.Field   files = Class.forName ("java.io.DeleteOnExitHook").getDeclaredField  ("files");

    run.setAccessible (true);
    files.setAccessible (true);

    run.invoke (null);
    files.set (null, new java.util.LinkedHashSet <String> ());
```

Alternatively, just retrieve the scheduled files with

```
    files.get (null)
```

iterate the set and delete the files manually, also deleting the names from the set as you go.  This way you can decide which files to delete yourself.